# Testing site with Google search console without allowing it to be publicly listed

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We are in a process of redesign, and would like to test a way google sees our website, but we would not like it to be indexed it at this point.

We have a separate subdomain for development, but if we disallow scraping in robots.txt, we can't do any tesing, because google crawlers will not scrape any testing pages.

Is there a way to run some tests via google webmasters console without allowing site to be indexed publicly?

Comment: @B001 so it will work normally, but will not be visible by google search engines?

Comment: @B001 write it as an answer, and will mark as answered. Documentation states you are saying well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `noindex` tag.

The `noindex` value of an HTML robots meta tag requests that automated Internet bots avoid indexing a web page. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex)

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to do it in that way, but I think it should work for you. You can close your domain with HTTP Basic Authentication. And add your login and passwords to URL when you adding your domain to Google Console. Smth like that https://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/

Comment: _I didn't try to do it in that way, but I think it should work for you..._ This is the reason why this answer should be a comment _at best_